# Create sliding animation with Jquery like on Flusta.com

Tags: jquery, animation, css

I would like to create sliding animation like on [Flusta.com](http://www.Flusta.com)
like the "text balloons" that move up after each other.

What would be a good Jquery animation library/plugin to use for such a feature?

Comment: How frustrating is, on the web, a link you cannot click on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try jQuery UI effects: http://jqueryui.com/docs/Effects/Methods
You should be able to achieve effect like on flusta.com using some combination of hide with sliding + show with bouncing effects.